# Is there a simple way to pass specific *named* PowerShell parameters through directly to a called function?

Tags: powershell, parameters, pass-through

I am sure I read somewhere that there is an easy way to pass named parameters from a calling function to a called function without explicitly naming and specifying each parameter.

This is more than just reusing the position; I'm interested in the case where the name of the passed parameters is the same in some cases, but not in others.

I also think there is a way that is not dependent on position.

```
function called-func {
    param([string]$foo, [string]$baz, [string]$bar)
    write-debug $baz
    write-host $foo,$bar
}

function calling-func {
    param([int]$rep = 1, [string]$foo, [string]$bar)
    1..$rep | %{
        called-func -foo $foo -bar $bar -baz $rep ## <---- Should this be simpler?
    }
}

calling-func -rep 10 -foo "Hello" -bar "World"
```

What would the method be, and is there a link?

I thought it might have been Jeffrey Snover, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I did do *some* googling first, but since I didn't see the answer already here on SO, I wanted to get it here too anyway.

Comment: So after some googling, I think the feature I was thinking of had to do with 'splatting' and passing switch parameters.  I'll post an answer after I get all the details.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell v2 (which admittedly you may not be ready to move to yet) allows you to pass along parameters without knowing about them ahead of time:

```
called-func $PSBoundParameters
```

PSBoundParameters is a dictionary of all the parameters that were actually provided to your function.  You can remove parameters you don't want (or add I suppose).

Comment: Yes, I can't wait till v2 goes to production :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I was confusing a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/01/02/how-and-why-to-use-splatting-passing-switch-parameters.aspx) I read about switch parameters.  As far as I can tell the best way is to just reuse the parameters like so:

```
called-func -foo:$foo -bar:$bar
```

Comment: The colon syntax is required when `foo` is a switch parameter. If you pass `-foo $foo` then `called-func` will think it's receiving two arguments (the switch `foo` and a value `$foo`).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
called-func  $foo $bar
```