# Get-ChildItem recurse as a parameter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

I am looking to create a function that could toggle the ability to recurse in [cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd772285.aspx) [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx).

As a very basic example:

```
...

param 
(   
    [string] $sourceDirectory = ".",
    [string] $fileTypeFilter = "*.log",
    [boolean] $recurse = $true
)

Get-ChildItem $sourceDirectory -recurse -filter $fileTypeFilter | 

...
```

How does one conditionally add the `-recurse` flag to Get-ChildItem without having to resort to some if/else statement?

I thought perhaps one could just substitute the `-recurse` in the Get-ChildItem statement with a `$recurseText` parameter (set to "-recurse" if $recurse were true), but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A couple of things here. First, you don't want to use [boolean] for the type of the recurse parameter.  That requires that you pass an argument for the Recurse parameter on your script e.g. `-Recurse $true`. What you want is a [switch] parameter as shown below.  Also, when you forward the switch value to the -Recurse parameter on Get-ChildItem use a `:` as shown below:

```
param (
    [string] $sourceDirectory = ".",
    [string] $fileTypeFilter = "*.log",
    [switch] $recurse
)

get-childitem $sourceDirectory -recurse:$recurse -filter $fileTypeFilter | ...
```

Answer (score 6):

The PowerShell V1 way to approach this is to use the method described in the other answers (-recurse:$recurse), but in V2 there is a new mechanism called [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx) that can make it easier to pass the arguments from one function to another.

Splatting will allow you to pass a dictionary or list of arguments to a PowerShell function. Here's a quick example.

```
$Parameters = @{
    Path=$home
    Recurse=$true
}
Get-ChildItem @Parameters
```

Inside of each function or script you can use `$psBoundParameters` to get the currently bound parameters. By adding or removing items to `$psBoundParameters`, it's easy to take your current function and call a cmdlet with some the functions' arguments.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234139) before... My accepted answer was basically that in v1 of PowerShell, just passing the named parameter through like:

```
get-childitem $sourceDirectory -recurse:$recurse -filter ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to work in v1, it seems to treat it as the next parameter.

get-childitem -recurse $true
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\src\True' because it does not exist.

Comment: sorry; use the : to join the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good list of the types of parameters you can use:

```
param(
    [string] $optionalparam1, #an optional parameter with no default value
    [string] $optionalparam2 = "default", #an optional parameter with a default value
    [string] $requiredparam = $(throw ""requiredparam required."), #throw exception if no value provided
    [string] $user = $(Read-Host -prompt "User"), #prompt user for value if none provided
    [switch] $switchparam; #an optional "switch parameter" (ie, a flag)
    )
```

From [here](http://www.lancerobinson.net/archive/2007/12/14/powershell-script---marking-a-parameter-as-required.aspx)